# Laravel image dimensions validation and error message

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a project that i develop using Laravel framework. I need to check if image that site visitor uploads meets the  image dimension requirements (width,height)
I do it in the following way

```
$this->validate(['banner_image'=>'dimensions:width=100,height=200']);
```

In case of wrong image dimension i want to display an error message in the following format

> Wrong dimensions. Required dimensions are :required_widthX:required_height and
> dimensions of file that you upload - :uploaded_widthX:uploaded_height

:required_width and :required_height are the dimensions that uploaded image must meat

:uploaded_width and :uploaded_height are the width and height of file that was uploaded

I generate the error message in the following way:

```
    'custom' => [
    'banner_image' => [
        'dimensions' => 'Wrong dimensions. Required dimensions are :widthX:height and dimensions of file that you upload - :uploaded_widthX:uploaded_height'
    ]
],
```

The :width and :height returns the width and height that are required. This works well
but my question is how to display width and height of image that was uploaded(:uploaded_width and uploaded_height).

P.S i don't know if this is important but i use  Livewire.

Comment: what do you see if you log getimagesize($this->banner_image)[0] before validation??

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think I see the direction of your thoughts. With  getimagesize($this->banner_image->getRealPath())[0]  i get the width of uploaded file and with [1] the height. Now i need a way to pass it to validation message.

Comment: it would be easier if you just showed the full livewire component, but i believe you can just put the 2 variables directly in the error message